# MySQL wont update from python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, wordpress, csv

Im reading a CSV file into python and am accessing the MySQL database from a hosted web server.

the CSV file compares to the data downloaded from the MySQL database but when it comes to commit the prices does not change. Im getting no errors.

```
import mysql.connector as db
import csv
try:
    mydb = db.connect(
        host="103.**.***.***",
        port = 3306,
        user="USER",
        passwd="PASSWORD",
        database="DATABASE"
        )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM wp_wc_product_meta_lookup")

    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    with open("stock.csv",encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            for x in myresult:
                if row['STOCK CODE'] == x[1]: # compare the stock code to the SKU
                    if row['RRP'] != str(x[4]): #compare the new price to the old
                        print(row['STOCK CODE'] + " needed to be updated")
                        price = row['RRP']
                        query =('''UPDATE ahfcompu_wp1.wp_wc_product_meta_lookup SET 
                        min_price=%s, max_price=%s WHERE    sku=%s'''% (price, price, x[4])); 
                        mycursor.execute(query)
                        mydb.commit()
                    else:
                        print("pass")
except Exception as a:
    print(a)
print ("done")
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated

***update***
CSV File

```
STOCK CODE,CATEGORY CODE,CATEGORY NAME,SUBCATEGORY NAME,SHORT DESCRIPTION,BAR CODE,DBP,RRP
NHU-TS-5-POE,NH,Network - Enterprise,EdgeMax Switching  Ubiquiti ToughSwitch 5port PoE Gigabit Managed Switch,8.17882E+11,119,159.72
```

Comment: You didn't commit the transaction.

Comment: First of all, in order to prevent SQL injection use `mycursor.execute(query, (price, price, x[4]))`

Comment: The table structure and CSV file structure would help identify the problem but it seems you're passing the wrong data for SKU; if `STOCK CODE == sku` then you should use `(price, price row["STOCK CODE"])` for the data you pass to the query.

Comment: @Dainel Roseman yes it's been committed at line of mydb.commit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a seperate tuple for values and include that in execute method.

```
query = """ UPDATE ahfcompu_wp1.wp_wc_product_meta_lookup SET 
                        min_price = %s, max_price = %s WHERE sku = %s """
values_tuple = (price, price, x[4])
mycursor.execute(query, values_tuple)
```